# How to fill an array from multiple comboboxes?

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I have 25 ComboBoxes that I want to move all of the values into an array so that i can put them into SQL Server. The current method that I am using is

```
string[] Answers = { cbxIntro.SelectedValue.ToString(), 
cbxAge.SelectedValue.ToString(), etc
```

This then throws up the error code

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of 
an object.'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `cbxIntro.SelectedValue` || `cbxAge.SelectedValue` is likely `null` and by casting the `SelectedValue` to a `string` is the error because it's null. Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `SelectedValue` wont do anything with *all the values*.

Answer (score -1):

sounds like one of your values is null try adding Coalesce and ifNotNull operators

ie

```
string[] Answers = { cbxIntro?.SelectedValue?.ToString() ?? "default", cbxAge?.SelectedValue?.ToString() ?? "default", ...
```

which reads as 
if cbxIntro is not null call SelectedValue 
if SelectedValue is not null call Tostring 
else return "default" string